# UIAlertView removeFromSuperview does not work

Tags: ios

I use the code below to show an UIAlertView

```
UIAlertView * messageBox = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"title"
                                                      message: @""
                                                     delegate: nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];



[messageBox show];
```

then I use a NSNotification postNotificationName to trigger and hope to remove or release the UIAlerView

```
-(void)notificationEntry:(NSNotification *)notification{

    if (messageBox ) {
        //[messageBox removeFromSuperview];//this does not work neither
        [messageBox performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        messageBox = nil;

    }
}
```

notification was triggered, but

```
[messageBox removeFromSuperview];

[messageBox performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview);
```

none works

Your comment welcome

Comment: I'm wondering, why are you trying to automatically remove an alert view?  Sorry but maybe there's a better way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It looks like you're declaring a local variable UIAlertView *messageBox and then accessing an ivar by the same name.

Comment: U cant remove it from super-view. U have to dismiss it with  **dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:** call to that instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: [`dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: This. Especially in iOS-7, messing about with alert views by trying to reach into it's view hierarchy is *strongly* discouraged and generally won't work. Treat UIAlertView as a black box object you can affect by calling methods and setting properties, *not* as a View you can manipulate like other views.